# python vlc, how to change a radio channel when button is pressed?

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc, pysimplegui, python-vlc

im trying to build a program (using pysimplegui) which contains a few buttons (play, stop, pause, next, previous) as you can see. and when i press "next" its stopping for some time and then the same music continues (i dont press "previous" because i know that will cause problem 0 - 1 = -1).
`

```
global n
n = 0
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer() 
url = ['http://cast.radiogroup.com.ua:8000/avtoradio', 'http://listen.rpfm.ru:9000/premium128', 'http://cast.loungefm.com.ua/terrace128']
media_player.set_mrl(url[n])
```

```
if event == 'play':
  media_player.play()

if event == 'stop': 
  media_player.stop()
     
if event == 'pause':
  media_player.pause()

if event == 'next':
  global n
  n + 1
  media_player.set_mrl(url[n])
  media_player.play()
        
if event == 'previous':
  n - 1
  media_player.set_mrl(url[n])
  media_player.play()
```

`

1. ive tried to google this problem
2. i didnt find the documentation
3. im trying to run it in a bit different way, using `

```
import vlc
playlist_url = ['http://cast.radiogroup.com.ua:8000/avtoradio', 'http://listen.rpfm.ru:9000/premium128', 'http://cast.loungefm.com.ua/terrace128']
n = int(input())
instance = vlc.Instance('--intf dummy')
player = instance.media_list_player_new() 
media = instance.media_list_new(playlist_url[n])
player.set_media_list(media)  
player.play()
```

`
but it returns
[0000027223bc32e0] filesystem stream error: cannot open file C:\Users\dadva\Desktop\Project\h (No such file or directory)
[0000027223ba3220] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0000027223ba3220] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///C:/Users/dadva/Desktop/Project/h'. Check the log for details.

Comment: In your first code: `n - 1` and `n + 1` don't do anything, the result of the calculation is immediately discarded. You probably want `n = n - 1` and `n = n + 1`. So when you hit "next", it stops playing, re-queries the (same) URL, and plays again. This is probably the short delay you notice.

Answer (score 0):

Demo Code

```py
import vlc
import PySimpleGUI as sg

playlist_url = [
    'http://cast.radiogroup.com.ua:8000/avtoradio',
    'http://listen.rpfm.ru:9000/premium128',
    'http://cast.loungefm.com.ua/terrace128',
]
n, m = 0, len(playlist_url)

player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
player.set_mrl(playlist_url[n])
player.play()

layout = [[sg.Button('PREV'), sg.Button('NEXT')]]
window = sg.Window('VLC Player', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('PREV', 'NEXT'):
        n = (n+1) % m if event == 'NEXT' else (n-1) % m
        player.set_mrl(playlist_url[n])
        player.play()

player.stop()
window.close()
```